# r - Overlay fileInput on leaflet in shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny, leaflet

I have a leaflet map in a shiny app. It takes a file from a user and plots that data. It's kind of ugly right now, though. I'd really like to have the fileInput to be overlaid on the leaflet map. In other words, I want the page to be entirely the leaflet map, but with the file input floating above it, similar to the zoom button.

I want the fileInput upload button to to look kind of like the elements of [this shiny app](https://birdcast.shinyapps.io/any_species_map2/?species=Swainson%27s%20Thrush;Wilson%27s%20Warbler;Blue-gray%20Gnatcatcher;Summer%20Tanager;Scarlet%20Tanager;Baltimore%20Oriole;Blue-headed%20Vireo;Red-eyed%20Vireo;Gray-cheeked%20Thrush;Ovenbird;Northern%20Waterthrush;Golden-winged%20Warbler;Blue-winged%20Warbler;Black-and-white%20Warbler;Nashville%20Warbler;Hooded%20Warbler;American%20Redstart;Cape%20May%20Warbler;Northern%20Parula;Magnolia%20Warbler;Blackburnian%20Warbler;Blackpoll%20Warbler;Black-throated%20Blue%20Warbler;Yellow-throated%20Warbler;Black-throated%20Green%20Warbler;Yellow-billed%20Cuckoo;Chimney%20Swift;Eastern%20Wood-Pewee;White-eyed%20Vireo;Yellow-throated%20Vireo;Philadelphia%20Vireo;Yellow-breasted%20Chat&countries=Maine,%20United%20States;New%20Hampshire,%20United%20States;Vermont,%20United%20States;Rhode%20Island,%20United%20States;Massachusetts,%20United%20States;Connecticut,%20United%20States;New%20York,%20United%20States;New%20Jersey,%20United%20States;Pennsylvania,%20United%20States;Nova%20Scotia,%20Canada;New%20Brunswick,%20Canada;Newfoundland%20and%20Labrador,%20Canada;Prince%20Edward%20Island,%20Canada&add_lines=FALSE&lines_direction=south&zoom=5&title=Neotropical%20transport&subtitle=Notable%20reports%20since%2026%20Oct%202017&start_date=2017-10-26&force_spp_legend=TRUE). It has logos overlaid on the top left, as well as checkboxes overlaid on the left and a title overlaid on the top right.

Here's a basic (over-simplified) outline of my app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)


shinyApp(
  ui <- bootstrapPage(
    fileInput("file_in", label = "label"),
    tags$style(type="text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
    leafletOutput("myMap", width="100%", height="100%")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    my_table <- reactive({

      inFile <- input$file_in
      if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)

      myData = read.csv(inFile$datapath)

      return(myData)
    })

    output$myMap = renderLeaflet({
      if(is.null(my_table()))
      {
        return(leaflet()) %>% addTiles()
      }
      else
      {
        leaflet(data = my_table()) %>% addTiles()
      }
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this by using `absolutePanel(..., fileInput())` in the ui.